# How to pass a value from one jsp to another jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp

I have two jsp pages:  `search.jsp` and `update.jsp`.

When I run `search.jsp` then one value fetches from database and I store that value in a variable called `scard`.  Now, what I want is to use that variable's value in another jsp page. I do not want to use `request.getparameter()`.

Here is my code:

```
<% 
String scard = "";
String id = request.getParameter("id");

try {
    String selectStoredProc = "SELECT * FROM Councel WHERE CouncelRegNo ='"+id+"'";

    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(selectStoredProc);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {
        scard = rs.getString(23);
    }

    rs.close();
    rs = null;
} catch (Exception e) {
    out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
} finally {

}
%>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Session attributes, go!

Comment: how can u explain demo

Comment: You can use the session, or if stateless use cookies

Comment: Those are keywords, use them.

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/session-implicit-object check this out

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using Query parameter

```
<a href="edit.jsp?userId=${user.id}" />
```

Using Hidden variable .

```
<form method="post" action="update.jsp">  
...  
   <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="${user.id}">
```

you can send Using Session object.

```
   session.setAttribute("userId", userid);
```

These values will now be available from any jsp as long as your session is still active.

```
   int userid = session.getAttribute("userId");
```

Comment: I didnt get the second option.

Comment: How do you send data using <a> tag? It is just used for moving from one page to another right? Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 8):

Use sessions

On your search.jsp

Put your `scard` in sessions using `session.setAttribute("scard","scard")`

`//the 1st variable is the string name that you will retrieve in ur next page,and the 2nd variable is the its value,i.e the scard value.`

And in your next page you retrieve it using `session.getAttribute("scard")`

**UPDATE**

```
<input type="text" value="<%=session.getAttribute("scard")%>"/>
```

Comment: how can i print this scard in next page

Comment: how can i print?u mean retrieve it on ur next page...using session.getAttribute("scard")

Answer (score 7):

Use below code for passing string from one jsp to another jsp

A.jsp

```
   <% String userid="Banda";%>
    <form action="B.jsp" method="post">
    <%
    session.setAttribute("userId", userid);
        %>
        <input type="submit"
                            value="Login">
    </form>
```

B.jsp

```
    <%String userid = session.getAttribute("userId").toString(); %>
    Hello<%=userid%>
```

Answer (score 1):

[How can I send data from one JSP page to another JSP page?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-send-data-from-one-JSP-page-to-another-JSP-page)
One of the best answer which I filtered out from above discussion.

Can be done in three ways:

1. using request attributes:
   Set the value to send in request attribute with a name of your choice as request.setAttribute("send", "valueToSend") and retrieve it on another jsp using request.getAttribute("send");
2. using session attributes
   Similar to above but using session object instead of request.
3. using application attributes
   Same as 1 and 2 above but using application object in place of request and session.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want to pass three values(u1,u2,u3) from say 'show.jsp' to another page say 'display.jsp'
Make three  hidden text boxes and a button that is click automatically(using javascript).
//Code to written in 'show.jsp'

```
<body>
<form action="display.jsp" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="u1" value="<%=u1%>"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="u2" value="<%=u2%>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="u3" value="<%=u3%>" />
 <button type="hidden" id="qq" value="Login" style="display: none;"></button>
</form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("qq").click();
  </script>
</body>
```

// Code to be written in 'display.jsp'

```
 <% String u1 = request.getParameter("u1").toString();
    String u2 = request.getParameter("u2").toString();
    String u3 = request.getParameter("u3").toString();
 %>
```

If you want to use these variables of servlets in javascript then simply write

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var a=<%=u1%>;
</script>
```

Hope it helps :)