# How to pass a string between 2 jsp pages?

Tags: mysql, jsp, netbeans

I want to pass a string between 2 jsp pages I have tried this but it didn't work :

**JSP Page 1**

```
String it=request.getParameter("select");

 request.setAttribute("remove", it);
```

**JSP Page 2**

```
String RemovedItem = request.getAttribute("remove");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass value from one jsp to another jsp page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369717/how-to-pass-value-from-one-jsp-to-another-jsp-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this:

The easiest is to pass attributes in **session** object.

**JSP1:**

```
session.setAttribute("param1","some value here");
```

**JSP2:**

```
String param1 = session.getAttribute("param1").toString();
session.removeAttribute("param1");
```

Another way is by using url parameters using the **response.sendRedirect()**:

JSP1:

```
response.sendRedirect("jsp2.jsp?param1=param value&param2=value for param2");
```

JSP2:

```
String param1 = request.getParameter("param1"); //param value
String param2 = request.getParameter("param2"); //value for param2
```