# How to pass data between JSP Pages using JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have 3 JSP pages, let's call it First.jsp Second.jsp Third.jsp. I would like to move data from First.jsp to Third.jsp. I know you can move data from using `<form action=".jsp" method="post">` as well as `<c:redirect url=.jsp> <c:param name= value=> </c:redirect>` however these will only work if both pages are connected to each other i.ex First.jsp and Second.jsp.

I've tried solution from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369717/how-to-pass-value-from-one-jsp-to-another-jsp-page). However, I don't really get the first solution which is using `<a ref/>`. But i tried it and it doesn't work. The second solution is like what i mentioned above. The third and fourth solution is not using JSTL if i recall correctly.

In my code, I would like to move option selected in dropdown list in First.jsp to Third.jsp

Here's my code for the drop down list

```
<s:setDataSource var="ds" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                 url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/project?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Pontianak&useSSL=false"
                 user="root" password="root"/>

<s:query dataSource="${ds}" var="resultseta">
    SELECT DISTINCT departureto, departurefrom FROM schedule
</s:query>

<body>

        From:
        <SELECT class="drop" style="WIDTH: 143px" id="departfromcmb" name="departfromcmb">
            <option value="">Select your location</option>
            <c:forEach items="${resultseta.rows}" var="departfromrow">
                <option value="${departfromrow.departurefrom}"> ${departfromrow.departurefrom} </option> //i would like to pass this data to third.jsp
            </c:forEach>
        </SELECT> <br><br>

        To:
        <SELECT class="drop" style="WIDTH: 150px" id="departtocmb">
            <option value="">Select your destination</option>
            <c:forEach items="${resultseta.rows}" var="departtorow">
                <option> ${departtorow.departureto}</option> //i would like to pass this code to third.jsp
            </c:forEach>
        </SELECT> <br><br>

</body>
```

Comment: This is probably too broad and there are duplicates for several solutions. Try storing data in a session or using hidden inputs.

Comment: Yes, Storing data in a session is not JSTL as far as i know. I've tried several solutions from another questions. None of them worked unfortunately.

Comment: I've edited my question. And put the link that refer to the solutions i've read before posting this question

Comment: ...you could use `<c:set var="..." value="..." scope="session" />`

Comment: ... but I would advice to use a controller to take care of that. Or, if you can, have a look at JSF.

Comment: and what should i put in third.jsp ?

Comment: I need to solve it with JSP and JSTL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info "Implicit EL objects"

Comment: I don't understand how to use '<c:set /> would be awesome if you can give me example. Also should we move to chat ?

Comment: Just tried to put `c<set var="from" value ="${departfromrow.departurefrom"` in First.jsp and tried to retrieve it in Third.jsp by doing `<c:out value="${param.from}"/>`, not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, putting all the stuff from the comments together:

**Page 1**

On this page you have the form posting to page 2:

```
<form action="page2.jsp" method="post>
  <input name="foo"/>
</form>
```

**Page 2**

Here we set the posted form field as a session attribute:

```
<c:set var="bar" value="${param.foo}" scope="session"/>
```

**Page 3**

Here we output the session attribute that was set on the previous page:

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.bar}"/>
```

Please note that, apart from [jstl](/questions/tagged/jstl), [el](/questions/tagged/el) plays an important role here. Session attributes are available through an implicit object.

See, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Comment: After all those trial and error I've done. I found out that `c:set` work if you use `<c:redirect>` and `<a href>` but not `<form action>`. Which is why i ended up using `<input value = hidden >` instead because i have to use `<form action>` in both first and second page

Comment: What are you saying? That sessions are not working for you?

Comment: `c:set` doesn't work with `form action method>` . What i've put in the `c:set` in first page can't be retrieved in the second page. It only works if i access the second page using `<c:redirect>` or `<a href>`

Comment: I do not see a `c:set` on the first page.

Comment: It was an example

Comment: Just tested it. Works fine.

Comment: Based on your answer above. How did you access Page 3 ?

Comment: That does not matter, since the `bar` is fetched from the session. A plain `<a href="page3.jsp">..</a>` will do, but a form will also be fine.